# layout cannot be resolved or is not a variable

Tags: android, layout

I cannot solve the error **layout cannot be resolved or is not a variable** in my MainActivity.java file. I'm wondering if there might be a problem in my xml files. This is my first time using the layout-land directory. I have activity_main.xml in the res/layout/layout-port directory and activity_main2.xml in the res/layout/layout-land directory

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.flash;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**res/layout-port/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**res/layout-land/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So change it back like this?

Comment: Also you forgot to put "android:layout_width" on your TableRow, that is important.

Comment: You're right I fixed that too.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same name for the layouts. Just call the two xml layouts "activity_main.xml"

Android knows what layout to use according the current configuration.

Read this doc: [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), look the examples over there.

Comment: I renamed the files, but the original problem remains.

Comment: can you post the log of the error(aka logcat)? Also clean the project after the change of the layouts names.

Comment: It just says I have to fix the errors before I run the application. I don't know how to display more details about the error.

Comment: Are your xml layouts posted here accurate? because you are closing the TableRow tag leaving out the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

also, in your 2nd main, you have an ill-formed xml:

```
<TableRow
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6" />
    </TableRow>
```

should be:

```
<TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6" />
    </TableRow>
```

this will prevent your resource file, R.java from being generated, which causes the layout not found error.

UPDATE:

not sure if you fixed your directory structure. it should look like this:

```
res/layout
res/layout-port
res/layout-land
```

NOT:

```
res/layout/layout-port, etc.
```

Comment: I edited my code to fix this problem as well, but the original problem remains.

Comment: @user2593697 Your `layout-land/activity_main` is also missing the closing `</LinearLayout>`